# Problema al mostrar resultado con console.log

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando `JS` para validar un formulario, quería hacer una prueba con una función para mostrar los datos que se encuentran en los *input* mediante la consola en el navegador, pero no me está mostrando nada.

Mi código:

- **vista**:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row my-5 d-flex justify-content-start">
            <div class="col-12 ">
                <h2>REGISTRO DE USUARIO</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col align-items-center">
                <form method="post" onsubmit="return validarRegistro()">
                    <div class="col-12 form-group" >    
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuarioRegistro"  id="usuarioRegistro" required class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="passwordRegistro" id="passwordRegistro" required class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailRegistro"  id="emailRegistro" required class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <input type="submit" id="submitRegistro" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-block btn-danger form-control">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El código de `JS` que tengo:

```
    function validarRegistro(){

        var usuario= document.querySelector("#usuarioRegistro").value;
        console.log('usuario',usuario);
        var password= document.querySelector("#passwordRegistro").value;
        console.log('password',password);
        var email= document.querySelector("#emailRegistro").value;
        console.log('email',email);

        return true;

    }
```

Conecto el código `js` a mi plantilla `HTLM` en el `<body>`:

```
<script src="views/js/validarRegistro.js"></script>
```

No sé que error tendré, pero tengo rato estancado allí, si alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionar el problema sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: ¿No te está mostrando nada o te está mostrando error/undefined?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No me muestra nada de nada, se queda en blanco la consola

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tu codigo funciona bien, el problema es que siempre estas retornando `true`, por eso no ves los valores en consola.

```js
function validarRegistro(){

        var usuario= document.querySelector("#usuarioRegistro").value;
        console.log('usuario',usuario);
        var password= document.querySelector("#passwordRegistro").value;
        console.log('password',password);
        var email= document.querySelector("#emailRegistro").value;
        console.log('email',email);

        return false;

    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row my-5 d-flex justify-content-start">
            <div class="col-12 ">
                <h2>REGISTRO DE USUARIO</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col align-items-center">
                <form method="post" onsubmit="return validarRegistro()">
                    <div class="col-12 form-group" >    
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuarioRegistro"  id="usuarioRegistro" required class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="passwordRegistro" id="passwordRegistro" required class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailRegistro"  id="emailRegistro" required class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <input type="submit" id="submitRegistro" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-block btn-danger form-control">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Acabo de realizar el cambio a false, pero no me funciona, cosa que no entiendo, porque en tu respuesta está perfecto

Comment: @Jesús Y te aseguraste de que esté llamando bien el script?

Comment: No estaría entendiendo, porque no haría los consoles si se retorna true? Si se hacen antes del return.

Comment: Si los hace pero no se ven porque la pagina se refresca muy rapido.

Comment: @Emeeus por que al retornar true se ejecuta el submit y la página se recarga

Comment: Ahora entiendo, buen punto

Comment: Cambie de pc y funciona perfecto así como me dices, la verdad me queda es la duda de por qué en la pc de mi trabajo no quería funcionar

Comment: Podria ser el browser que usaste.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que se hace notar y por lo que hace [@alanfcm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/81482/alanfcm) el código ya debería estar funcionando totalmente bien, sí no lo hace, me hace pensar que el problema sea que estás llamando mal el archivo o que no lo está tomando ya sea por algún problema en la ruta o en el nombre del documento, o donde lo estés importando
Así que, trata de poner

```
<script src="/mipag/views/js/validarRegistro.js"></script>
```

ó ponerlo en el `<head>`

```
<head> 
    <script src="/views/js/validarRegistro.js"></script> 
</head>
```

Y ya en ultimas hacer ambas opciones, espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Me aseguré de que estuviera bien la ruta, por alguna extraña razón, en la pc donde estaba probando el código no me funcionaba, ahora que estoy en mi casa y lo probé en mi pc funciona perfecto con lo que me dijo @alanfcm, Gracias igualmente!

Answer (score -2):

primero, le quitaría este return:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validarRegistro()">
                <div class="col-12 form-group
```

por lo demás funciona bien. yo puse el script en el body (con tags script) y sin problema. En todo caso, activa la página de desarrollo en el browser cuando corre la app (f12 en windows) y podrás ver en la pestaña de consola los errores, y con esa información corregir el problema.